# ios app crashes when adding sublayer AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer for custom camera

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am new to swift and Xcode and am trying to build a custom camera for my app. I am following this tutorial here:
https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Camera-View

I am using Xcode 8.1 and my ios deployment target is ios 10.0

The app runs fine until i add the videoPreviewLayer to the view. Here is the code

```
videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
videoPreviewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
videoPreviewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
previewView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
session!.startRunning()
```

The app crashes at the line

```
 previewView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
```

Error in the console

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2016-12-13 00:03:43.274268 smarticannativetest2[682:172753] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I also get the following

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode=0x1002f51ec)
```

What am i doing wrong and how can i make it work?
Thanks

Comment: Your preview layer is probably failing to get created. Place a breakpoint after your call videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session) to see if it is nil.

Comment: it is being created. here is when i print the previewlayer Optional(<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer:0x170226840; position = CGPoint (0 0); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 0 0); sublayers = (<CALayer: 0x170226660>); masksToBounds = YES; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; >)

Comment: Ok, do you also check for previewView?

Comment: i just did. printing previewView prints nothing it is empty

Comment: it did print <UIView: 0x100c0de70; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x170223200>>

Comment: but i noticed that this code is being executed twice, and printed twice. the second time previewView didnt print

Comment: viewWillAppear is being called twice and the second time the previewView is nil

Comment: You will need to post more of your source code to determine. There isn't enough here to determine without knowing how you create your AVCaptureSession